# What is the correct statement of Theorem 4.2 in Street's "Parity Complexes"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Ross Street's 1991 paper [Parity Complexes](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1991__32_4_315_0/) (apologies; I don't know how to find DOI links for *Cahiers* papers) develops some very useful tools for working with free strict $\omega$-categories. There is a [corrigenda](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1994__35_4_359_0/) to the paper. I find it a bit difficult to assemble together these two ingredients to be sure what are the correct statements of the main theorems in Street's paper. A useful later reference for this material is Buckley's [Formalizing Parity Complexes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.02297).

I am interested in understanding Theorem 4.2, which unfortunately is not covered in Buckley's treatment. The theorem states

> Theorem 4.2 The $\omega$-category $O(C)$ is freely generated by the atoms.

Let's break that down:

1. As indicated in the paper, the notion of "free generation" comes from Street's earlier [The Algebra of Oriented Simplices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(87)90137-X). I believe this notion is to be read as-is without change from the corrigenda.
2. I believe that as originally written (but see (5) below), $C$ was intended to be an arbitrary [parity complex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/parity+complex), a notion defined in Section 1 of the paper; I believe this definition is faithfully reproduced at the linked nlab page (the nlab's $<$ being Street's $\triangleleft$ and the nlab's $\prec$ being Street's $\blacktriangleleft$).
3. $O(C)$ is the $\omega$-category defined at the beginning of Section 3. It is proven in Theorem 3.6 that for any parity complex $C$, $O(C)$ is an $\omega$-category. I believe that Theorem 3.6 is understood to be true as stated -- the corrigenda does not indicate that the definition of $O(C)$ (or the subsidiary notions of *cells* or *well-formed subsets of $C$*) need be changed, nor does it indicate that any additional hypothesis on the parity complex $C$ is needed to ensure that $O(C)$ is an $\omega$-category (Thm 3.6).
4. The notion of an *atom* is as defined in Section 4 of the paper.
5. I believe the corrigenda indicates that the statement of Thm 4.2 should be changed as follows. On p. 1 of the corrigenda, it is indicated that for every element $x \in C_p$ of the parity complex $C$, we need to assume throughout Section 4 (including, apparently, in the statement of Thm 4.2) that the sets $\mu(x)$ (defined at the beginning of Section 4, with the definition corrected at the beginning of the corrigenda) are *tight* in the sense defined further down p. 1 of the corrigenda.

Therefore, I believe the correct statement of Theorem 4.2 is:

> Theorem 4.2, *correcta*: Let $C$ be a parity complex. Assume that for every $p \in \mathbb N$ and every $x \in C_p$, the sets $\mu(x)$ (as defined in the corrigendum, not as defined in the paper) are *tight* (as defined in the corrigendum). Then the $\omega$-category $O(C)$ is freely generated by the atoms.

**Question 1:** Do I have that right?

The corrigendum also defines a notion of *globularity* at the beginning of p.2, and I *believe* the corrigendum asserts that for every parity complex $C$, and for every *relevant* $x \in C_p$ (as defined in Section 4), the globularity condition holds for $x$. I believe that Prop 5.2 of the corrigendum gives a criterion ensuring that the globularity condition holds for all $x \in C_p$, not just for the *relevant* $x \in C_p$. This condition uses the corrected definition of $\mu(x)$ as well as the corrected definition of $\pi(x)$.

**Question 2:** Can the corrected statement of Theorem 4.2 be simplified by assuming something about the "globularity condition" rather than explicitly assuming something about tightness?

Comment: Experts will come. Meanwhile, maybe related papers: Henry, "Non-unital polygraphs form a presheaf category". Hadzihasanovic, "A combinatorial-topological shape category for polygraphs". Gagna et al, "Nerves and cones of free loop-free ω-categories".

Comment: I've just noticed two things I don't understand. First, what is $\mu(x)$? Is it the union $\mu(x) = \cup_{n=0}^p \mu(x)_n$? (and similarly for $\pi(x)$?) Second, Street says in the corrigendum that in Section 4 we must assume $\mu(x)$ is tight for every $p$ and every $x \in C_p$ -- but should we also assume that $\pi(x)$ is tight?

Comment: The person you want to talk to here I think is Simon Forest. I don't know if he is on MO, but you can have a look at his paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00282.pdf where among other thing he shows that the theore; you are talking about is actually false without some additional assumptions.

Comment: @SimonHenry Thanks. I am confused (and my confusion was not alleviated by reading Forest's paper without delving into the proofs) -- Street already provided a corrigendum correcting the statement of Theorem 4.2. Is Forest saying that the _original_ statement of Theorem 4.2 is false (which was already "known", or at least expected), or is he saying that the _corrected_ version of Thm 4.2 is false?

Comment: I assume the corrected version is still false. But I'm not very familiar with this... You should ask Simon Forest or read his paper.

Comment: It _appears_ that in Forest's definition on p. 12 (unfortunately, Forest, like Street, does not number all his definitions!) he adds a condition to the definition of a parity complex (the condition needed for Street's _corrected_ claimed Thm 4.2 -- even though Street never made this condition part of a "corrected definition" of a parity complex), so that on p. 13 his counterexample is presumably something satisfying this condition... so I think I agree he's refuting the corrected version. But he doesn't explicitly say which version he's refuting!

Comment: @TimCampion: $\mu(x)$ is the graded set made of the $\mu(x)_p$.

Comment: (Timer for editing, sorry) No, assuming the tightness of $\mu(x)$ is sufficient. As I said in my reply below, Theorem 4.2 does not hold fully with or without the corrigenda. Concerning the fact I made tightness part of the definition of Street, it seemed acceptable, since for me a parity complex should be defined so that the original statement of Theorem 4.2 holds for this definition. Also, Street's approach concerning his axioms seems to be "whatever works", so that morally tightness can be made part of the definition without too much concern.

Comment: @SimonForest I definitely agree it seems appropriate to modify the definition of parity complex in order to get 4.2 to go through; I was just confused that you did this without commenting about how the definition you use compares to what Street says in either of the two versions of his work. The bottom line is that Street's work, though groundbreaking, left us with a bit of a mess. Fortunately, it seems that you have cleaned up the mess completely! I think it just pays to be clear about what the cleanup job entailed, and not to downplay it out of excessive modesty.

Comment: @TimCampion: Sorry about that … My article was already too long, so that I had to put a stop to details and remarks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I can offer some quick answers to your questions without errors.

Let's tackle the breaking down:

> 1. As indicated in the paper, the notion of "free generation" comes from Street's earlier [The Algebra of Oriented
>    Simplices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(87)90137-X). I believe
>    this notion is to be read as-is without change from the corrigenda.

Yes, it is the notion of freeness of this article. Using some rephrasing, it
means that there exists a polygraph/computad $P$ such that $O(C)$ is isomorphic
to $P^*$, the free $\omega$-category on $P$.

> 2. I believe that as originally written (but see (5) below), $C$ was intended to be an arbitrary [parity
>    complex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/parity+complex), a notion
>    defined in Section 1 of the paper; I believe this definition is
>    faithfully reproduced at the linked nlab page (the nlab's $<$ being
>    Street's $\triangleleft$ and the nlab's $\prec$ being Street's
>    $\blacktriangleleft$).

It seems that the well-formed condition of parity complexes is badly
reproduced in the nlab (condition 2.). Indeed, it not only a condition on the 1-cells but
also on higher cells. Moreover, nlab's $<$ is Street's $<$ and nlab's $\prec$
is Street's $\triangleleft$.

> 3. $O(C)$ is the $\omega$-category defined at the beginning of Section 3. It is proven in Theorem 3.6 that for any parity complex
>    $C$, $O(C)$ is an $\omega$-category. I believe that Theorem 3.6 is
>    understood to be true as stated -- the corrigenda does not indicate
>    that the definition of $O(C)$ (or the subsidiary notions of *cells* or
>    *well-formed subsets of $C$*) need be changed, nor does it indicate that any additional hypothesis on the parity complex $C$ is needed to
>    ensure that $O(C)$ is an $\omega$-category (Thm 3.6).

If I remember correctly, yes, the additions of the corrigenda is not required
in order to obtain an $\omega$-category. So one can start from any parity complex.

> 4. The notion of an *atom* is as defined in Section 4 of the paper.

Yes.

> 5. I believe the corrigenda indicates that the statement of Thm 4.2 should be changed as follows. On p. 1 of the corrigenda, it is
>    indicated that for every element $x \in C_p$ of the parity complex
>    $C$, we need to assume throughout Section 4 (including, apparently, in
>    the statement of Thm 4.2) that the sets $\mu(x)$ (defined at the
>    beginning of Section 4, with the definition corrected at the beginning
>    of the corrigenda) are *tight* in the sense defined further down p. 1
>    of the corrigenda.

Yes, this correta seems correct to me, in the sense that it should be the one deduced from the corrigenda.

> **Question 2:** Can the corrected statement of Theorem 4.2 be simplified by assuming something about the "globularity condition"
> rather than explicitly assuming something about tightness?

No, it can not be simplified to a globularity condition. The counter-example I gave in [my
article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00282) is a parity complex which satisfies the globularity condition. Still,
Theorem 4.2 does not hold for this example.

By the way, it is no coincidence that Theorem 4.2 of Street's paper is not covered by Buckley, since it does not hold in its full generality with or without the [corrigenda](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1994__35_4_359_0/) (but the counter-examples, like the already cited one, are very peculiar, so that most if not all the examples which use parity complexes in the literature should be fine).

Comment: Thanks so much! So if I understand correctly, my reading of Street's paper was correct, but the paper was wrong. My reading of Street's corrigenda was correct, but the corrigenda were _still_ wrong. You showed this in the counterexample on p. 13 of your paper.

Comment: I approve that but I would say that Street's paper was "not fully correct" instead of "wrong" :) As you said above, his paper still contains fundamental tools and ideas, which were necessary for me to find a fix, so that "wrong" feels to much discarding…